# Find a determined <span> and insert an id on the container element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="divname">
    <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT1</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT2</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT3</span></a>
</div>
```

It's a pager. YouTube's pager, you can check it out (`divname == "branded-page-box search-pager  spf-link"`)

I need to find `CONTENT3` and add an id to the `<a>` containing it.

Is this doable using JavaScript? I've tried with different approaches but can't get it working.

Comment: What do you want where?

Comment: Use `document.QuerySelectorAll("a.linkname")` to find all the links, loop over the list, use `element.innerHTML` to get the contents, and use `element.id = "newID"` to assign the ID.

Comment: Are you looking for a plain JS solution or jQuery? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to want to do here is first select your main container by class `document.getElementsByClassName('branded-page-box search-pager spf-link')[0]` and then find all link elements within it. Loop through the links and find the one with the content matching your search and set the ID of it's parent to whatever your custom ID is.

Example:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('branded-page-box search-pager spf-link')[0].getElementsByClassName('spanclass');

var i, span;

for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i += 1) {
  span = spans[i];

  if (span.innerHTML === 'CONTENT3') {
    span.parentNode.id = 'your_custom_id';
    // break here if you only want to find the first match
  }
}
```

```css
#your_custom_id {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="branded-page-box search-pager spf-link">
  <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT1</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT2</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="linkname" data-sessionlink="" aria-label=""><span class="spanclass">CONTENT3</span></a>
</div>
```

You can alternatively use `var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.branded-page-box.search-pager.spf-link .spanclass');` for the first line if you don't need to support IE8 or older.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.linkname'); // Find all the links

for (var i in links) { // Loop through the links

  var link = links[i]; // Get the current link

  if (link.textContent === 'CONTENT3') { // Check the link's text content
    link.id = 'theChosenOne'; // Add the id if the text content was correct
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably don't want to literally look for **CONTENT3** you could filter by the 3rd instance and select the inner html and apply it to the link `id` like so, https://jsfiddle.net/6cge9rLb/2/

```
<script>
$( "span" ).filter(function( index ) {
   if (index === 2){
        var innerText = $( this ).html();
       $(this).parent().attr('id', innerText);
   }
  });
</script>
```